# How do I print data from database via PHP and JSON without form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm needing to send a JSON via 2 text fields, one textfield contains the URL that will be where the JSON to be sent and the other contains the JSON command.

as shown in the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="form1" class="send"> 
<p>URL:<input type="text" name="url2" id="url2" /></p>
<p> JSON:<textarea name="json" id="json" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" class="button" name="send" value="send" id="send" /></p>
</div>
<p></p>
<p>
<div id="status">
  RETURN:
  <textarea name="return" id="return" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
</p>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$(function(){
    $('#form1 input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
        //console.log($("#json").val());
        e.preventDefault();
       // var json  = $("#json") .val();
         var json  = $.parseJSON($("#json").val());

        var url2 = $("#url2") .val();
        $.ajax({
            url:url2,
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data:json,
            async:true,
            //data:{json: json},
            //afterSend: function (){
            //$(".status") .html(" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
            //console.log("");
            //},
            success:function(data){
                        showComment();
                //console.log(data);
                //console.log(data.response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

SEARCH PHP

```
include('conection.php');
$arr = json_decode($_POST['send'],true);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE client_descricao='".$arr[0]['client_descricao']."' OR client_razaosocial ='".$arr[0]['client_razaosocial']."' OR client_endereco ='".$arr[0]['client_endereco']."' OR client_cidade ='".$arr[0]['client_cidade']."' OR client_estado ='".$arr[0]['client_estado']."' OR client_telefone ='".$arr[0]['client_telefone']."'")or die(mysql_error());
$json = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json);
```

REGISTER PHP

```
include ('conection.php');
$arr = json_decode($_POST['json'],true);
if ($_POST['json']>NULL){

mysql_query("INSERT INTO liciteiro.clientes(client_id,client_descricao,client_razaosocial,client_endereco,client_cidade,client_estado,client_telefone) VALUES ('".$arr[0]['client_id']."','".$arr[0]['client_descricao']."','".$arr[0]['client_razaosocial']."','".$arr[0]['client_endereco']."','".$arr[0]['client_cidade']."','".$arr[0]['client_estado']."','".$arr[0]['client_telefone']."')")or die(mysql_error());

$response = array("success" =>true);
}
else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

But I also have another textarea that I would have returns data sent, for example: I send json command to fetch a record in the database would return me the data in this textarea if I Ever Made up a register appear-a registration message successfully confirmed or something.

Comment: You can leave the word `urgent` out of your questions. It will more likely have the opposite effect than you hope for.

Comment: And where's the problem? Your code seems all right. Does that "console.log(data);" print correct answer? Use Your browser's developer tools (F12 in Chrome and FF) to see the actual http requests and responses going on. Also use var_dump($_POST); in your PHP to be sure what request you are really receiving.

Comment: in console.log it returns nothing.
I would like to return the data from the database when Ever Made up a requisition or a search on the server.